# Writing a List to Parcelable?

Tags: java, android, list, parcelable

I have a custom object that has `private List<AnotherCustomObject> mList;`. Note that `AnotherCustomObject` implements `Parcelable`.

However if I want to write `mList` to `dest` in `writeToParcel()` and then read it back later, is this the correct way:

`dest.writeList(mList);`

and then in the read method

`in.readList(mList, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());`

Correct?

Comment: Have you tried doing this?

Comment: It doesn't throw errors but that doesn't make it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use necessary classloader.

```
in.readList(mList, AnotherCustomObject.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Is there a difference betweeen `.class` and `.getClass()`?

Comment: Better will be static access via `.class`

Answer (score 0):

Your `List<AnotherCustomObject> mList` can be read using the `readTypedList(List<T> list, Creator<T> c)` method and written to using the `writeTypedList(List<T> val)` method.

In your `writeToParcel` method you would write the following:

```
dest.writeTypedList(mList);
```

And then in the constructor which creates an instance from a `Parcel` object you can put:

```
in.readTypedList(mList, AnotherCustomObject.CREATOR);
```